# <Forge Viewer> Nothing is displayed by a browser.

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

A model was displayed normally until last week.
But Nothing is displayed by a Browser Today.

The following log is displayed to a Chrome-console.

```
GET                                      viewer3D.min.js:4
   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/<MyUrn>
   401 (Unauthorized)
```

Was there the change of specifications about any OAuth or Derivative API?
Is there the method avoiding this error?

I used [this](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-node.js-view.and.data.api) as reference.

Comment: It was wrong. It was normal until yesterday not last week.

Answer (score 1):

We have solved the problem by ourselves.
It was the bug of viewer3D.min.js(Ver2.11).

I changed Javascript URL.

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
              ↓
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=2.10.*"></script>
```

Thank you for All.